# How to verify GET request values in ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm new to ansible and I'm trying to figure out how I can verify values in a GET request.

Here is my GET request:

```
    #
    # GET Results
    #
    - name:Results
      uri:
       url: "https://getresults.com"
       method: GET
       user: "{{ user }}"
       password: "{{ pass }}"
       status_code:
         - 200
         - 202
       validate_certs: no
       return_content: yes
       headers:
         Content-Type: "application/json"
      ignore_errors: true
      register: new_task_results
```

Here is the values returned from my GET request:

```
 "content_length": "296", 
        "content_type": "application/json", 
        "cookies": {}, 
        "cookies_string": "", 
        "date": "Fri, 02 Jun 2021 14:24:21 GMT", 
        "elapsed": 0, 
        "failed": false, 
        "json": {
            "dataProducts": [], 
            "id": "xyzg777-2479-4f23-b835-5675e58eef22", 
            "name": "UPDATE", 
            "priority": 1, 
            "processor": null, 
            "qualityOfService": {
                "frequency": 1, 
                "intervalSeconds": 800
            },
```

How do I verify that "priority" is 1 and the "id" is correct?

Comment: is it the debug of new_task_results?

Answer (score 1):

```
- debug:
    msg: "priority is 1 and id is correct"
  when: _p == 1 and _i == 'xyzg777-2479-4f23-b835-5675e58eef22'
  vars:
    _p: "{{ new_task_results.json.priority | int }}" 
    _i: "{{ new_task_results.json.id }}"
```